# Getting the .class filename and path after Executing ProcessBuilder in java

Tags: java, file-io, processbuilder

I created an API that will take payload `(code, language)` which in turn generates a random name to **save the file(based on the language the extensions will get selected) from java**. payload from UI is below

```
{"code": "class Demo{  \r\n" + 
            "    public static void main(String args[]){  \r\n" + 
            "     System.out.println(\"Hello Java\");  \r\n" + 
            "    }  \r\n" + 
            "}",
"language": "java"}
```

File saving is working properly as expected and I'm able to save the file under  **`C:\\temp`**, but the problem occurs when I'm trying to execute those saved files with  **`ProcessBuilder`** in java, getting `Error: Could not find or load main class BNkHZk`(as the randomly generated file name is different from the class file after executing the below code).

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "javac", fullPath });
//fullPath is C:\temp\BNkHZk.java
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

the above execution will create a new **Demo.class** file.
After Executing the above command, I'm executing the below code

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "javac", fullPath });
Process process = processBuilder.start();
            if (process.getErrorStream().read() != -1) {
                System.out.println("Compilation Errors" + process.getErrorStream());
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.Println(line);
            }
```

I'm getting the below error
**`Error: Could not find or load main class BNkHZk`**

The complete function is below as below

```
    private void ExecuteCode(String language, String code){
    String tempFileName = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(6);
    // Code to creating the file and save under "C:\\temp\\"
    String fullPath = "C:\\temp\\" + tempFileName+ "." + language;
    try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File(fullPath));
            fileWriter.write(code);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception while creating new file");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileWriter != null) {
                fileWriter.close();
            }
        }
    
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "javac", fullPath });
                ////fullPath is C:\temp\BNkHZk.java
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            if (process.getErrorStream().read() != -1) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
 //the above execution will create a new **Demo.class** file.
            int exitcode = -1;
            try {
                exitcode = process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (exitcode == 0) {
                (
                    processBuilder  = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "java","tempFileName"});//BNkHZk
                        Process process1 = processBuilder.start();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                        String line = "";

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line + "\n");
                        }
            }
            
}
```

I'm getting  **`error Error: Could not find or load main class BNkHZk`**

Note: Since I'll get the content of the file as String, I'm not able to save the **filename** same as **`.class`** name. Is there any workaround to save the filename as same as **.class** name ??
Any workaround suggestions are appreciated and welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different issues. The first one is the naming of the class file. The name of the class must be match the name of the file. `class Demo -> Demo.java`, that's why you can't use random filenames. The compile runs well, but not the run.

The second one is the handling of the ProccessBuilder. I suggest the following pattern:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("javac.exe", "Demo.java");
pb.directory(Paths.get("path_to_java_file").toFile());
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
try (var infoStream = process.getInputStream()) {
    infoStream.transferTo(System.out);
}
status = process.waitFor();
```

Now you can see, if the compile runs correctly.

Use the same pattern to run your compiled class.

Comment: Hi @Thilo Schwarz, thanks for the quick response. Since I'll get the content of the file as String, I'm not able to save the filename the same as the .class name.

Comment: @UllasSharma You get your source code as text, right? You should save this code as java file, ```Demo.java```. The next step is the compilation with javac, right? The result of the compilation is the file ```Demo.class```.  Or did I misunderstood the workflow?

Comment: @Ullas Sharma just create a temp directory and then the expected Java file inside it in  the generation step - `Path fullPath = Path.of("C:/temp", tmpFileName, "Demo." + language);` and then the above will work from inside the temp dir

Comment: @ Thilo Schwarz, I get the content as text only, but I won't be getting the exact className of  file, as it's dynamic content. for example, if you see JSON req i'll be getting from UI like `{"code": "class Sample{  public static void main(String args[]){  System.out.println(\"Hello Java\"); }",
"language": "java"}` as per your understanding filename should be `Sample.java` ,but I'm not able to get the className itself as it's kind of challenging to make it from dynamic text content.

Comment: @DuncG i'm looking for workaround with processbuilder to get the newly created `.class` name, 
the content as text only, but I won't be getting the exact className of the file, as it's dynamic content. for example, if you see JSON req I'll be getting from UI like `{"code": "class Sample{  public static void main(String args[]){  System.out.println(\"Hello Java\"); }",
"language": "java"}` as per your understanding filename should be `Sample.java` ,but I'm not able to get the className itself as it's kind of challenging to make it from dynamic text content.

Comment: @UllasSharma, if your json  req contains java code, you should be able to parse the code to find out the class name. This could be done e.g. by regex. Otherwise you can't compile and run it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle in two ways.

If you have a recent version of Java you can simply skip the "javac" step and launch "java" and the class will be auto-compiled and auto-run even if the name of the class is not matching the name of the `.java` file.

So if your temp generated java file was `"\\Temp\\XYZ.java"` then this would compile and run, printing `Hello Java`:

```
Path fullPath = Path.of("/Temp", "XYZ.java").toAbsolutePath();  // wherever
var pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "java", fullPath.toString() });
...
```

If you don't have a recent version of Java keep your "javac" step but write the file to a newly created directory used only for this single generated Java file:

```
Path fullPath = Path.of("/Temp", "wherever", "ANYNAME.java").toAbsolutePath();
var pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "javac", fullPath });
...
```

Then look at contents of `fullPath.getParent()` and to find the file with extension `.class`, deduce the class name from the filename before the file extension and use your "java" step with that derived classname and with the classpath directory set to `fullPath.getParent()`. For example the second stage would look like:

```
String fn = Files.list(fullPath.getParent()).map(Path::getFileName).map(Path::toString).filter(s -> s.endsWith(".class")).findFirst().get();
String className = fn.substring(0, fn.lastIndexOf('.'));
var pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "java", "-cp", fullPath.getParent().toString(), className });
...
```

Comment: thanks for the workaround... it solved my problem temporarily.